# Openstack keystone issue

Tags: openstack

i am having an issue with keystone,keystone is configured with users nova,glance and admin user and their endpoints are also defined.
when performing

```
keystone token-get
```

it is showing token,but for commands like

```
keystone user-list
```

its showing

```
No handlers could be found for logger "keystoneclient.client"
Unable to communicate with identity service: 404 Not Found
The resource could not be found.
 . (HTTP 404)
```

but after setting these env variables it worked

```
export SERVICE_ENDPOINT=http://192.168.10.15:35357/v2.0
export SERVICE_TOKEN=token
```

but after that for **keystone  token-get** its showing

```
'Client' object has no attribute 'service_catalog'
```

Why is it so?How can it be fixed any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this is a potential answer.  Might not be THE answer.

But it sounds to me like the issue you are having is a connectivity issue to the "Admin" API of keystone.

Keystone client will typically begin a query by getting a token from the 'Service' API.  This API defaults to port 5000 and is configurable in the keystone conf file.  It will also grab a service catalog that it will use to find the Admin API endpoint.

Then to perform Administrative functions it will query the 'Admin' API.  This API defaults to 35357 and is configurable in the keystone conf file.

So if the 'Admin' API was unavailable this would exhibit the behaviour you are seeing.

There are two ways to go about verifying that there is a connectivity issue with the 'Admin' API available to you.

The most useful approach is to set the debug flag for the keystone client.  It will out put extra information about the queries it is making.

Example ( from a throw away devstack ):

```
stack@devstack:~/devstack$ keystone --debug user-list
REQ: curl -i http://192.168.122.236:5000/v2.0/tokens -X POST -H "Content-Type:   application/json" -H "User-Agent: python-keystoneclient"
REQ BODY: {"auth": {"tenantName": "demo", "passwordCredentials": {"username": "admin", "password": "stack"}}}

RESP: [200] {'date': 'Wed, 20 Mar 2013 23:25:09 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': '5983', 'vary': 'X-Auth-Token'}
RESP BODY: {"access": {"token": {"issued_at": "2013-03-20T23:25:09.917153", "expires": "2013-03-21T23:25:09Z", "id": "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-zCB-AIBATBcMFcxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQ4wDAYDVQQIEwVVbnNldDEOMAwGA1UEBxMFVW5zZXQxDjAMBgNVBAoTBVVuc2V0MRgwFgYDVQQDEw93d3cuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20CAQEwBwYFKw4DAhowDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEgYB1E4lLmIkSot4Yggwjs3p71EXg9vMan0wX4SM5sFgsH6GrJBwJ4LPzG7HQX8wNMYaa6qMN5EWowx6+RktGHYiBOjGxGFPpWIEUcU0loAINa8QkrPMUfDfIvJDuaXR0eTEQQsaujmgqqjD9N5KuZ+t30i324T2dowD8ihdqEjGJKQ==", "tenant": {"description": null, "enabled": true, "id": "45e7cd57b9ef4871891f53e75aeb5727", "name": "demo"}}, "serviceCatalog": [{"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://192.168.122.236:8774/v2/45e7cd57b9ef4871891f53e75aeb5727", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://192.168.122.236:8774/v2/45e7cd57b9ef4871891f53e75aeb5727", "id": "56f826e61af94daa88a2dbf8c9cd07cb", "publicURL": "http://192.168.122.236:8774/v2/45e7cd57b9ef4871891f53e75aeb5727"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "compute", "name": "nova"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://192.168.122.236:3333", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://192.168.122.236:3333", "id": "666e71bd93f04b1c9ac081db03750fcb", "publicURL": "http://192.168.122.236:3333"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "s3", "name": "s3"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://192.168.122.236:9292", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://192.168.122.236:9292", "id": "5d1d026917254d5ab5b9d4d556e6800e", "publicURL": "http://192.168.122.236:9292"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "image", "name": "glance"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://192.168.122.236:8776/v1/45e7cd57b9ef4871891f53e75aeb5727", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://192.168.122.236:8776/v1/45e7cd57b9ef4871891f53e75aeb5727", "id": "02cbbdcbcea748679ffa90305ff96e19", "publicURL": "http://192.168.122.236:8776/v1/45e7cd57b9ef4871891f53e75aeb5727"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "volume", "name": "cinder"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://192.168.122.236:8773/services/Admin", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://192.168.122.236:8773/services/Cloud", "id": "6234f3763c5f48eaa0f41156ace90ea2", "publicURL": "http://192.168.122.236:8773/services/Cloud"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "ec2", "name": "ec2"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://192.168.122.236:35357/v2.0", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://192.168.122.236:5000/v2.0", "id": "0831b45f2f4b4a80ada0782372258b8c", "publicURL": "http://192.168.122.236:5000/v2.0"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "identity", "name": "keystone"}], "user": {"username": "admin", "roles_links": [], "id": "71b6e3604b744b90bdbb948b80a3e678", "roles": [{"name": "admin"}], "name": "admin"}, "metadata": {"is_admin": 0, "roles": ["07ac476e82904c5dbe1dd82f1987f019"]}}}

REQ: curl -i http://192.168.122.236:35357/v2.0/users -X GET -H "User-Agent: python-keystoneclient" -H "X-Auth-Token: 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-zCB-AIBATBcMFcxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQ4wDAYDVQQIEwVVbnNldDEOMAwGA1UEBxMFVW5zZXQxDjAMBgNVBAoTBVVuc2V0MRgwFgYDVQQDEw93d3cuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20CAQEwBwYFKw4DAhowDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEgYB1E4lLmIkSot4Yggwjs3p71EXg9vMan0wX4SM5sFgsH6GrJBwJ4LPzG7HQX8wNMYaa6qMN5EWowx6+RktGHYiBOjGxGFPpWIEUcU0loAINa8QkrPMUfDfIvJDuaXR0eTEQQsaujmgqqjD9N5KuZ+t30i324T2dowD8ihdqEjGJKQ=="
RESP: [200] {'date': 'Wed, 20 Mar 2013 23:25:09 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': '863', 'vary': 'X-Auth-Token'}
RESP BODY: {"users": [{"name": "alt_demo", "id": "00f1ffdaa14f448da11630edc3503e92", "tenantId": null, "enabled": true, "email": "alt_demo@example.com"}, {"name": "demo", "id": "445391568d1d4b619e7919462deeab63", "tenantId": null, "enabled": true, "email": "demo@example.com"}, {"name": "admin", "id": "71b6e3604b744b90bdbb948b80a3e678", "tenantId": null, "enabled": true, "email": "admin@example.com"}, {"name": "glance", "id": "7971cdee1ac0496499ea87828a24309b", "tenantId": "a5c7110f23ac495e805d4ebeefeff0b6", "enabled": true, "email": "glance@example.com"}, {"name": "nova", "id": "a2dda6286156444fa44308b43c934c89", "tenantId": "a5c7110f23ac495e805d4ebeefeff0b6", "enabled": true, "email": "nova@example.com"}, {"name": "cinder", "id":      "c5340dffe39d4ae4b17e2441bf1392d5", "tenantId": "a5c7110f23ac495e805d4ebeefeff0b6", "enabled": true, "email": "cinder@example.com"}]}

+----------------------------------+----------+---------+----------------------+
|                id                |   name   | enabled |        email         |
+----------------------------------+----------+---------+----------------------+
| 71b6e3604b744b90bdbb948b80a3e678 |  admin   |   True  |  admin@example.com   |
| 00f1ffdaa14f448da11630edc3503e92 | alt_demo |   True  | alt_demo@example.com |
| c5340dffe39d4ae4b17e2441bf1392d5 |  cinder  |   True  |  cinder@example.com  |
| 445391568d1d4b619e7919462deeab63 |   demo   |   True  |   demo@example.com   |
| 7971cdee1ac0496499ea87828a24309b |  glance  |   True  |  glance@example.com  |
| a2dda6286156444fa44308b43c934c89 |   nova   |   True  |   nova@example.com   |
+----------------------------------+----------+---------+----------------------+
```

The benefit here is you will see where it tries to connect to the Admin API.  It will query the service API for a service catalog when choosing an API endpoint for the Admin API.  So ensure that your service catalog directs people to the right API endpoint for the Admin API of keystone.

Alternatively you can simply strace the keystone client query.

More info about the differences in functionality between the service and admin API's available to Keystone:

http://docs.openstack.org/developer/keystone/api_curl_examples.html

Answer (score 1):

```
root@sc9200mit7-kvm:/etc/keystone# keystone --os-username=admin --os-password=Chennai123 --os-auth-url=http://<IPADDRESS>:35357/v2.0 token-get
'Client' object has no attribute 'service_catalog'
```

Restarting the keystone services, fixed the issue as below

```
root@sc9200mit7-kvm:~# service keystone restart
keystone stop/waiting
keystone start/running, process 14423

root@sc9200mit7-kvm:~# keystone --os-username=admin --os-password=Chennai123 --os-tenant-name=chennai --os-auth-url=http://<IPADDRESS>:35357/v2.0 token-get
+-----------+----------------------------------+
|  Property |              Value               |
+-----------+----------------------------------+
|  expires  |       2013-11-10T12:22:50Z       |
|     id    | d355c0aeadc2419e929d4d50fcc9b354 |
| tenant_id | a600776ea11a41f2acf4a03e5d3baea0 |
|  user_id  | a8490f832d7243b9a40d576d9c649fa8 |
+-----------+----------------------------------+
```